# Magento 2: Display Custom attribute value under the product name on category page

Tags: magento2, category, attributes, product-attribute, magento-2.1.3

I want to display custom attribute value  under the product name on category page.

Attribute type is dropdown and attribute name is Brand.

I want to display the brand name under the product name on category page in **GRID** and **LIST** mode.

How can i do that?  What's the standard way to display brand name under product name?

Do i need to create any module for that or custom function?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 10):

**Edit below file**

> app/design/frontend/CUSTOM/THEME/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/list.phtml

```
$attribute = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('attribute_code');
```

**// Get Value**

```
$attributeValue = $attribute->getFrontend()->getValue($_product);
```

**// Get Label**

```
$attributeLabel = $attribute->getStoreLabel();
```

**Note:** Make sure “**Visible on Product View Page on Front-end**” and “**Used in Product Listing**” options under storefront Properties are set to **Yes**.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. How do you display the attribute (control the output product name) on the product details page though? I would like to display Capacity just under the product name "title". Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php/***********Display Brand Attribute************/?>
<?php
$om = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$attribute = $om->get(\Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductAttributeRepositoryInterface::class)->get('manufacturer');
?>
<ul>
<?php
if($attribute){
    foreach ($attribute->getOptions() as $option) {
        $name = $option->getLabel();
        $optId = $option->getValue();
        $curnt_cat_url = $category->getUrl();
        $brandId = '?manufacturer='.$optId;

        $swatchHelper=$om->get("Magento\Swatches\Helper\Media");
        $swatchCollection = $om->create('Magento\Swatches\Model\ResourceModel\Swatch\Collection');

        $swatchCollection->addFieldtoFilter('option_id',$optId);
        $item=$swatchCollection->getFirstItem();
        $ThumbImage =  $swatchHelper->getSwatchAttributeImage('swatch_thumb', $item->getValue());
        //$SwatchImage = $swatchHelper->getSwatchAttributeImage('swatch_image', $item->getValue());
?>
        <?php if ($optId) { ?>
            <div class="brand_bg">
                <li class="brand_img_bg"> 
                    <a href="<?php echo $curnt_cat_url.$brandId ?>"><img src="<?php echo $ThumbImage; ?>"></a>
                </li>
                <!--<a href="<?php //echo $curnt_cat_url.$brandId ?>"><?php //echo $name; ?></a>-->
            </div>
        <?php } ?>
    <?php } ?>
<?php } ?> 
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you follow Abhishek Panchal answer above even-then your custom attribute value noe displaying on category pages the confirm you had not enabled this attribute for catalog pages:
edit the attribute select:

```
storefront properties -> Used in Product Listing -> yes
```

Comment: Man you saved my time.