# How to add attribute to product grid?

Tags: php, template, magento2.4.1

I would like to add the sku attribute to my product widget. Here is the original Magento code-

```
<?php
/**
* Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
* See COPYING.txt for license details.
*/
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action;

/** @var \Magento\CatalogWidget\Block\Product\ProductsList $block */
?>
<?php if ($exist = ($block->getProductCollection() && $block->getProductCollection()->getSize())) : ?>
<?php
$type = 'widget-product-grid';

$mode = 'grid';

$image = 'new_products_content_widget_grid';
$items = $block->getProductCollection()->getItems();

$showWishlist = true;
$showCompare = true;
$showCart = true;
$templateType = \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ReviewRendererInterface::SHORT_VIEW;
$description = false;
?>
<div class="block widget block-products-list <?= /* @noEscape */ $mode ?>">
    <?php if ($block->getTitle()) : ?>
        <div class="block-title">
            <strong><?= $block->escapeHtml(__($block->getTitle())) ?></strong>
        </div>
    <?php endif ?>
    <div class="block-content">
        <?= /* @noEscape */ '<!-- ' . $image . '-->' ?>
        <div class="products-<?= /* @noEscape */ $mode ?> <?= /* @noEscape */ $mode ?>">
            <ol class="product-items <?= /* @noEscape */ $type ?>">
                <?php $iterator = 1; ?>
                <?php foreach ($items as $_item) : ?>
                    <?= /* @noEscape */ ($iterator++ == 1) ? '<li class="product-item">' : '</li><li class="product-item">' ?>
                    <div class="product-item-info">
                        <a href="<?= $block->escapeUrl($block->getProductUrl($_item)) ?>" class="product-item-photo">
                            <?= $block->getImage($_item, $image)->toHtml() ?>
                        </a>
                        <div class="product-item-details">
                            <strong class="product-item-name">
                                <a title="<?= $block->escapeHtml($_item->getName()) ?>"
                                   href="<?= $block->escapeUrl($block->getProductUrl($_item)) ?>"
                                   class="product-item-link">
                                    <?= $block->escapeHtml($_item->getName()) ?>
                                </a>
                            </strong>
                            <?php if ($templateType) : ?>
                                <?= $block->getReviewsSummaryHtml($_item, $templateType) ?>
                            <?php endif; ?>

                            <?= $block->getProductPriceHtml($_item, $type) ?>

                            <?= $block->getProductDetailsHtml($_item) ?>

                            <?php if ($showWishlist || $showCompare || $showCart) : ?>
                                <div class="product-item-inner">
                                    <div class="product-item-actions">
                                        <?php if ($showCart) : ?>
                                            <div class="actions-primary">
                                                <?php if ($_item->isSaleable()) : ?>
                                                    <?php $postParams = $block->getAddToCartPostParams($_item); ?>
                                                    <form data-role="tocart-form" data-product-sku="<?= $block->escapeHtml($_item->getSku()) ?>" action="<?= $block->escapeUrl($postParams['action']) ?>" method="post">
                                                        <input type="hidden" name="product" value="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($postParams['data']['product']) ?>">
                                                        <input type="hidden" name="<?= /* @noEscape */ Action::PARAM_NAME_URL_ENCODED ?>" value="<?= /* @noEscape */ $postParams['data'][Action::PARAM_NAME_URL_ENCODED] ?>">
                                                        <?= $block->getBlockHtml('formkey') ?>
                                                        <button type="submit"
                                                                title="<?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Add to Cart')) ?>"
                                                                class="action tocart primary">
                                                            <span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Add to Cart')) ?></span>
                                                        </button>
                                                    </form>
                                                <?php else : ?>
                                                    <?php if ($_item->getIsSalable()) : ?>
                                                        <div class="stock available"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('In stock')) ?></span></div>
                                                    <?php else : ?>
                                                        <div class="stock unavailable"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Out of stock')) ?></span></div>
                                                    <?php endif; ?>
                                                <?php endif; ?>
                                            </div>
                                        <?php endif; ?>
                                        <?php if ($showWishlist || $showCompare) : ?>
                                            <div class="actions-secondary" data-role="add-to-links">
                                                <?php if ($this->helper(\Magento\Wishlist\Helper\Data::class)->isAllow() && $showWishlist) : ?>
                                                    <a href="#"
                                                       data-post='<?= /* @noEscape */ $block->getAddToWishlistParams($_item) ?>' class="action towishlist" data-action="add-to-wishlist" title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Add to Wish List')) ?>">
                                                        <span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Add to Wish List')) ?></span>
                                                    </a>
                                                <?php endif; ?>
                                                <?php if ($block->getAddToCompareUrl() && $showCompare) : ?>
                                                    <?php $compareHelper = $this->helper(\Magento\Catalog\Helper\Product\Compare::class);?>
                                                    <a href="#" class="action tocompare" data-post='<?= /* @noEscape */ $compareHelper->getPostDataParams($_item) ?>' title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Add to Compare')) ?>">
                                                        <span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Add to Compare')) ?></span>
                                                    </a>
                                                <?php endif; ?>
                                            </div>
                                        <?php endif; ?>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            <?php endif; ?>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <?= ($iterator == count($items) + 1) ? '</li>' : '' ?>
                <?php endforeach ?>
            </ol>
        </div>
        <?= $block->getPagerHtml() ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

Following a different post [Magento 2 : How can I display an attribute on the category page?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/235364/magento-2-how-can-i-display-an-attribute-on-the-category-page) I added

```
$attribute = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('sku');
$attributeValue = $attribute->getFrontend()->getValue($_product);
$attributeLabel = $attribute->getStoreLabel();
```

and

```
<h1 style="color: #ff6e17"><?php echo $_product->getData('sku'); ?></h1>
```

But I get the undefined variable error. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like in your `<h1>` you wrote $product instead of $_product

Comment: I edited that in. That was the problem with the original, but after that it worked. It doesn't work on 2.4.1