# How to display product attributes on products page magento 2.1

Tags: magento-2.1, product-attribute

Please see attached screenshot:
[![enter image description here][1]][1]

I created one custom product attributes ETA_DATE and I want to display same as attached image.
How to display this attribute on product page?

[image]

Comment: Hello, did you found solution ?

Comment: No, I updated my question. Do you know how can I do?

Comment: edit: {Magento2Root}/app/design/frontend/{Package}/{theme}/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/list.phtml and call 

<?php echo getEtaDate(); ?> Or <?php echo getAttributeText(eta_date); ?>

Comment: Duplcate - https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/191613/magento-2-display-custom-attribute-value-under-the-product-name-on-category-pag/191621#191621

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below code to get custom attribute value.

```
<?php echo $this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Output')->productAttribute($block->getProduct(), $block->getProduct()->getEtaDate(), 'Eta_Date')); ?>
```

**Update:**

> app/design/frontend/CUSTOM/THEME/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/list.phtml

```
$attribute = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('attribute_code');
```

**// Get Value**

```
$attributeValue = $attribute->getFrontend()->getValue($_product);
```

**// Get Label**

```
$attributeLabel = $attribute->getStoreLabel();
```

**Note:** Make sure “**Visible on Product View Page on Front-end**” and “Used in Product Listing” options under storefront Properties are set to **Yes**.

**Update:**

```
<?php 
if(!$_product->getIsSalable()):
    $attribute = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('eta_date'); 
    $etaDate = $attribute->getFrontend()->getValue($_product); 
    $newDate = date("d/m/Y", strtotime($etaDate));
    $etaLabel = $attribute->getStoreLabel(); 
    echo $etaLabel." ".$etaDate;
endif;
?>
```

Comment: In which file I'll use this code?

Comment: if you want it after "Add to cart" button then `app\design\frontend\Vendor\theme\Magento_Catalog\templates\product\view\addtocart.phtml` use this file.

Comment: this code is not working and I find addto cart file:vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/addtocart.phtml               I use this code but it doesn't show me custom attributes.

Comment: What exactly your attribute code is? Its all Capital letters? Also, make sure that your file is coming from theme or from vendor?

Comment: my attribute code is eta_date and I copy addtocart.phtml from vendor to app/design folder but this code is not working.

Comment: Can you specify full path? app/design..? Is your attribute is assigned to proper attribute set and visible on frontend to YES?

Comment: copied from vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/view/addtocart.phtml      to 
  
  
 app/design/frontend/Solwin/freego/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/view/addtocart.phtml

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/86445/discussion-between-abhishek-panchal-and-kiran).